Querying subscription documents that match object
I have subscriptions collection in the database, e.g:
[{
  _id: new ObjectId(...),
  query: {
    size: { $in: [1, 2, 3] }
  }
}, {
  _id: new ObjectId(...),
  query: {
    name: { $eq: 'Shirt' },
  }
}]

I need to find all subscriptions whose query matches the object. Is it possible? E.g:
Subscriptions.aggregate([{
  $reverseMatch: {
    size: 1,
    name: 'Shirt',
  },
}]);


It may be me but I'm not sure I understand. Can you share a sample document that and you hope to match or does your document actually have a field named query with a value of { size: { $in: [1, 2, 3] } } ?

@jQueeny yes, the document in the database has a field named query with that value. I've updated the question to make it clear.

You can do this or this or combined in an $or like this or an exact match like this. Is that the kind of thing your looking for? These can be converted easily to an aggregate with match like this or this

@jQueeny yes, but query can be anything, I don't know the structure of query in advance.

I suspect there is some design flaw here. The worst case I can think of is that you need to iterate the whole subscriptions collection's documents one by one in application level and run the query to see if they can match your provided object. Can you better explain what is your use case and what are you trying to do?

If I get it right the OP is asking about reverse search, something similar to percolate query on ElasticSearch. @karaxuna, could you confirm if it is the case and update the question. It's quite niche and I recall I was struggling to implement it myself few years ago.

Assuming OP is asking about functionality similar to percolate query on ElasticSearch, it's not a design flaw, but rather a niche requirement.
The short answer is "NO" - there is no way to implement it with an arbitrary query stored in a document.
The problem lays in the separation between data and commands on protocol level. A json stored as a value remains data for life. There is no way to use it as a command / filter / query or any other control structure. Basically it's fundamentally not possible to store a query / filter with native mongodb syntax  in the database to run it against a document / collection on db side itself.
What you can do:
implement own dsl similar to mongodb syntax
generally impossible task, but if you can limit query syntax to reasonable operations you can end up with something useful. An example below implements $eq and $in queries as in the OP. I didn't test it thoughtfully, it's there just to demonstrate scale of complexity of the approach.
db.Subscriptions.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "query": {
        "$objectToArray": "$query"
      },
      "doc": {                               // <== the document to query against
        $objectToArray: {
          "size": 1,
          "name": "Shirt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "match": {
        "$reduce": {                        // <== query parser
          "input": "$query",
          "initialValue": true,
          "in": {
            $and: [                         //  <== logical AND for all fields in the query
              "$$value",
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $size: {
                      "$filter": {            // <== number of matching fields in the document
                        "input": "$doc",
                        "as": "prop",
                        "cond": {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              "$eq": [
                                "$$prop.k",
                                "$$this.k"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $or: [                // <== filtering engine
                                {
                                  "$eq": [          // <== $eq matcher
                                    "$$prop.v",
                                    "$$this.v.eq"    
                                  ]
                                },
                                {
                                  "$in": [          // <== $in matcher
                                    "$$prop.v",
                                    {
                                      "$ifNull": [
                                        "$$this.v.in",
                                        []
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "match": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "doc": 0,
      "match": 0
    }
  }
])

And even for this approach the syntax for the "query" field in the subscription document should be adjusted to avoid $ sign:
[{
  _id: new ObjectId(...),
  query: {
    size: { in: [1, 2, 3] }
  }
}, {
  _id: new ObjectId(...),
  query: {
    name: { eq: 'Shirt' },
  }
}]

implement matching engine in javascript
Using $function gives you much more flexibility. It would be easier to implement the matching engine there, but it comes with massive performance impact, and it will likely be disabled for security, so won't go into details on this one. Just mentioning it as an option. Again, reaching 100% compatibility for arbitrary query is an enormous task, so you will need to put reasonable limitations on supported syntax.
implement on application level
If the subscription collection is reasonably small (like 1,000s to 10,000s of documents), you can load all documents to the serverside application, and run the queries in parallel. By default driver's pool is 100 connections, which lets you run 100 subscription queries at a time.
You will need to store the
{
    size: 1,
    name: 'Shirt',
}

document in a temporary collection, and run the subscription queries against it.

Subscriptions.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $nor: [
        { "query.size": 1 }, // Exclude documents where size is 1
        { "query.size": 2 }, // Exclude documents where size is 2
        { "query.size": 3 }  // Exclude documents where size is 3
      ]
    }
  }
]);

This query effectively filters out subscriptions where the size field inside the query object matches any of the specified values (1, 2, or 3), thereby giving us the subscriptions that do not match the specified object. It's a neat way to handle such filtering requirements in MongoDB aggregation pipelines.

Hey, thanks! But this does not answer my question.

@karaxuna is there any correlation in the documents in subscriptions collection? Also when you say "find all subscriptions whose query matches the object" is that Query is and condition or OR condition? If you could elaborate more with exact sample records and expected results then problem can be understood and solved.

Considering you have two collections cloths and subscriptions one can think of following https://mongoplayground.net/p/F9WHoCcLYh7
here first we match the subscription filter and get matched subscription, then do lookup to actual collection for matched subscription then finally filter matched results with required criteria... If you are still thinking of one collection and you are just saving query for subscription then you might need to run the matched queries on target collection and then get the final results.
